# Mapping private field to a column not working in EF Core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework-core

In a class, I have a private field:

```
private string _extraSettings;
```

which I map to a column named ExtraSettings with the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>(e =>
{
    e.Property<string>("ExtraSettings").HasField("_extraSettings").UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
});
```

This works fine in EF Core 2.2 but stopped working in EF Core 3.1 with the following error:

```
The specified field '_extraSettings' cannot be used for the property 'MyClass.ExtraSettings' because it does not match the property name
```

The MyClass class does not have ExtraSettings property, but for some reason this worked in 2.2 - why it doesn't work in 3.1 and what do I need to do to get rid of this error?

Comment: This is [a known and documented breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#field-only-property-names-should-match-the-field-name)

Comment: So now the only way is to introduce ExtraSettings property while I don't need it?

Comment: according to the docs and [the linked issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15307) in the `Mitigations` section, this should have worked in 3.1, without specifying `UsePropertyAccessorMode`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos May be they are planning it for EF Core 5.0!

Comment: @TanvirArjel no, they released this in EF Core 3.1. [The tests are there already](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v3.1.0/test/EFCore.Tests/ModelBuilding/NonRelationshipTestBase.cs#L864)

Comment: @zdev are you *sure* you're using EF Core 3.1? Which version? What does the `PackageReference` line in `csproj` look like?

Comment: Their code from Mitigation section (without UsePropertyAccessorMode) does not work. Version 3.1.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [EF Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#field-only-property-names-should-match-the-field-name):

> a field-only property must match the field name exactly.

So you can do as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>(e =>
{
    e.Property<string>("_extraSettings").HasColumnName("ExtraSettings");
});
```

Comment: That section says that a later version would fix that, and the linked issue is closed in EF Core 3.1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are correct! I saw your link. then why OP's code is not working?

Comment: Worked for me as well, tried with .net 5